# Проверка на наличие данных в БД

Tags: mysql, node.js, telegraf

помогите решить проблему. Есть такой код, всё вроде просто донельзя, бот одобряет заявку в канал, проверяет есть ли данный человек в БД и если нет, то создает. Но проблема в следующем: даже если человек уже есть в БД, он продолжает создавать новые строки.

```js
bot.on('chat_join_request', async (ctx) => {
    bot.telegram.approveChatJoinRequest(ctx.chat.id, ctx.from.id)
        .then(() => {
            let user = Mysql.Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ? AND channelID = ?", [ctx.from.id, ctx.chat.id])
            if (!user[0]) {
                let regUser = { id: ctx.from.id, channelID: ctx.chat.id }
                return Mysql.Query("INSERT INTO users SET ?", regUser)
            }
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
});
```

Comment: Покажите что возвращается в переменную user

Comment: Может, нужно явно добавить в ``INSERT INTO users SET ?", regUser`` еще ``channelId``  ?